# Formatting of entire column based on the grand total using color scale?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, colors, conditional-formatting

This might be answered somewhere else, but I haven't been able to find a solution to this. The question is how to use color scale for entire column just based on grand total.

I have attached the picture for reference.

I am happy with the color scale on the grand total and want the entire column to take up that color but if I copy the format it turns the entire color scale goes haywire. e.g. I want entire column `ab` to become green instead of having yellow in 4 rows and green in 3rd as well as all the grand total turned green.

Is there any way to link it up?

```
Criteria    er  ab  bc  cd  de  ef
ABC         2   3   2   1   2   1
XYZ         1   3   1   1   2   1
low         1   3   1   1   1   1
high        1   3   2   1   2   1
Grand Total 14  19  16  12  16  13
```

Comment: What picture? Did you attach it? Because your question is very much about the colour, would be very useful :)

Comment: Are you using conditional formatting?

Comment: Hi The website didn't let me add picture but if you take the data and copy it to excel and do color scale in conditional formatting, you will get the picture...

Comment: Can you try to add the picture again, even as a link. We can edit your post to get it right for you :)... It will make things easier, especially as I don't currently have access to Excel

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/86ycbvngf/1499718b/

Comment: Hi I have uploaded and posted a link for the picture Dave

Comment: I hope the question is clear now with the link to the picture...